# How to replace all local files to server through TFS in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Actually I want to upload all local code/files to server by TFS. But in VS2012, it will not show conflict for some files which are differ from server. And also not upload that files to server. 
I had checkout all files and checkin.
I want my server folder exactly like local folder.

How to upload all local files to server?

Answer (score 0):

under source control, select the folder that is mapped to your local folder. right click on the folder in source control. click add items to folder. this will open up a window where you can choose which items in your workspace you want to add to source control. once all the files have been added you can then do the checkin